# Nested unordered_map for storing a directed graph's adjacency list

Tags: c++, graph, nested, unordered-map, adjacency-list

I am working with a nested unordered_map, i.e., `std::unordered_map<int,std::unordered_map<int,int>> adjList`, for representing a directed graph's adjacency list.

If I am given the edges E={(u,v),(u,w),(u,z)}, how do I go about inserting these into the nested unordered_map? Part of my ignorance is I think I am having a hard time visualizing the nested unordered_map and how it works here. If someone could explain in words, and maybe programmatically, that would be great.

Comment: Can you explain a bit about what the template variables in your `std::unordered_map<int,std::unordered_map<int,int>> adjList` are supposed to represent

Comment: This is meant to be for a directed graph. So I am letting the template variables represent the start and end node IDs (integers) for a given edge.

Comment: So the key is the edge ID? I guess I don't follow why the "value" is an `unordered_map`?

Comment: No, the key is what I am calling a "node id." I was told that an efficient way to represent an adjacency list could be with a nested `unordered_map` where the value of the key-value pair is represented as an `unordered_map`. So I'm trying to implement this but it's confusing me.

Comment: Perhaps a better "value" would be an `unordered_set` or even a `std::vector` to be  honest. As it stands now it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: And apparently `adjList[u][v]` would mean that `u` is the key to the outermost hash table, and `v` is the key to the inner most hash table.

Comment: `adjList[u][v]` implies an adjacency *matrix*, which you could do with a nested `std::vector` or nested `std::array`

Comment: Hmm I see. I can try that instead (regarding your second to last comment)! I was previously using a vector of vectors for the adjacency list, but I was told that my implementation was not very efficient in regards to search time and deletion times, and a suggestion was that I use a nested unordered_map.

Comment: adjacency list and adjacency matrix have their pros and cons, it's whatever suites your needs better ;-) vector of vectors should be fairly fast for search times, so I'm not sure what your colleague is getting at. Doesn't scale very well in memory, though. Perhaps they wanted to use hash tables to represent some kind of "on demand" check for the empty spaces, which I suppose could be *okay* in a sparse matrix, but sparse hash tables are generally poor choices for cache locality reasons.

Comment: It is definitely a sparse matrix for my application (neural networks), which is why I opted to use adjacency lists. Isn't the search time for a vector of vectors, in the worst-case scenario, `m_0+...+m_(N-1)`  (the total number of elements in the vector of vectors)?  Where N is the size of `adjList` and `m_1....m_(N-1)` is the number of elements in (or size of) `adjList[0]....adjList[N-1]`?

Comment: @lamanon: search time should be O(1) with an adjacency matrix. It should be a matrix of true/false values. If you wish to know if an edge exists or not, you ask `adjMatrix[i][j]`

Comment: Sorry, I meant search time for an adjacency list for a directed graph, and I meant in terms of, say, you're given a node v, and you want to find the set of nodes that form the edge E=({u},v). (basically find all edges where v is the end node). It seems the search time using a vector of vectors for this would be pretty computationally expensive?

Comment: In both an adjacency matrix and adjacency list this amounts to walking the row for `v`. They both have complexity O(V).